# Can I change a model-viewer texture using an uploaded file? (client side)

Tags: javascript, html, model-viewer

### The challenge

The goal is to allow users to upload their textures to preview on the model-viewer model.

### What I tried so far

1. I made it work but instead of `<input type="file">` using `<input type="text">`.
2. I can make an uploaded image display as a `<img>` element.

### Example

https://jsfiddle.net/pynrdk25/11/

```js
document.getElementById("urlA").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const file = this.files[0];

  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    document.getElementById("modelA").model.materials[0].pbrMetallicRoughness.baseColorTexture.texture.source.setURI(this.value);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85)
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size:  16pt;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4a5a8a
  
}
model-viewer {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #484E61
}
input[type="file"] {
  margin: 15px auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer@1.12.0/dist/model-viewer-umd.js"></script>
<h1>Upload an image to preview it in the model</h1>
<input type="file" id="urlA">
<model-viewer
id="modelA"
camera-controls
src="https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb"
shadow-intensity="0"
environment-image="neutral"
exposure="0.5"
></model-viewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about model-viewer or what texture you're trying to change, but I can provide details on why your code is not obtaining the content of the file properly.

You need to subscribe to the `load` event on `FileReader` and access the `result` property to obtain the generated data URI.

```js
document.getElementById("urlA").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const file = this.files[0];
  const viewer = document.getElementById("modelA");

  if (!file) return;

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', async function() {
    const texture = await viewer.createTexture(reader.result);
    viewer.model.materials[0].normalTexture.setTexture(texture);
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85)
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size:  16pt;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4a5a8a
  
}
model-viewer {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #484E61
}
input[type="file"] {
  margin: 15px auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer@1.12.0/dist/model-viewer-umd.js"></script>
<h1>Upload an image to preview it in the model</h1>
<input type="file" id="urlA">
<model-viewer
id="modelA"
camera-controls
src="https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb"
shadow-intensity="0"
environment-image="neutral"
exposure="0.5"
></model-viewer>
```